# Search and count how many times do the specific command appears in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've searched and found nothing. This is what my test case looks like :

```
console.log(specificSearch([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
  ], 'even')); // the maximum number of even numbers is in row - 2, which are 2 and 8

  console.log(specificSearch([
  ['o', 'o', 'o', 'x'],
  ['x', 'x', 'o'],
  ['o', 'x'],
  ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x']
  ], 'x')); // the maximum number of x is in column - 4, which is 7 times appear
```

and this is my code so far :

```
function specificSearch(array, command) {

    var max = 0
    var even = 0
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
      var evenCounter = 0
       for(var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){
          if(command === 'even'){
             if(array[i][j] % 2 == 0){
                evenCounter++
             }
          } 
       }

       if(command === 'even' ){
         if( max < evenCounter) {
           max = evenCounter
           even = i
         }
       }
    }
    return even
  }
```

that's when I try to search even number, if it search number then it has to return in row and what number but in other hand if it doesn't search number and the length of array is not same then it needs return in what column and how many times appear.
This case needs no built in function such as regex, map, filter, index just use looping and array operation such as push, pop, shift etc

Thank you for your helping, I am just a noob who try to learn code :)

Comment: please add the wanted result. do you want to get the row/column **and** the count? what happens if the count in row/column is equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could hand over a function for checking a specific value and return a boolean value for the check.

- for `even` take

  ```
  x => !(x % 2)`
  ```
- for an identity check take

  ```
  x => x === 'x'
  ```

Then you could collect all counts in rows and columns arrays and get later the maximum value and return from the `rows`/`cols` arrays the indices with the maximum value.

The result is an object with the maximum count of a row/column and the indices where the maximum count occurs.

BTW, this answer uses the indices as they work in Javascript, starting at zero. If you need to start with one, just add one to every index.

```js
function specificSearch(array, checkFn) {

    function getIndices(array, value) {
        var i, indices = [];
        for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] === value) indices.push(i);
        }
        return indices;
    }

    var i, j,
        rows = [],
        cols = [],
        max;

    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            if (checkFn(array[i][j])) {
                rows[i] = (rows[i] || 0) + 1;
                cols[j] = (cols[j] || 0) + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    max = Math.max(...cols, ...rows);
    return { max, rows: getIndices(rows, max), cols: getIndices(cols, max) };
}

console.log(specificSearch([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], x => !(x % 2)));
console.log(specificSearch([['o', 'o', 'o', 'x'], ['x', 'x', 'o'], ['o', 'x'], ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x']], x => x === 'x'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

> This case needs no built in function

Usually when you want to turn an array into one value you use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const specificSearch = (array, comparer) =>
  array.reduce((highest, items) => {
    //reduce to highest number
    const current = items.reduce(
      //reduce to number
      //if comparer returns true for item add 1 to sum
      (sum, item) => (comparer(item) ? sum + 1 : sum),
      0,//start with sum of 0
    );
    //if current result is higher than highest so far
    //  return current, else return highest
    return current > highest ? current : highest;
  }, 0/** start with highest value of 0 */);

console.log(
  "max times even in item array",
  specificSearch(
    [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]],
    (x) => x % 2 === 0,
  ),
);

console.log(
  "max times value of 'x' in item array",
  specificSearch(
    [
      ['o', 'o', 'o', 'x'],
      ['x', 'x', 'o'],
      ['o', 'x'],
      ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'],
    ],
    (x) => x === 'x',
  ),
);
```

If you see the code snippet then you'll notice it is possible to turn the array into a number with the inner reduce and the outer reduce picks the highest number.

The inner reduce uses a comparer function that's passed in by the caller of `specificSearch` to indicate when the sum needs to increase, now the caller can determine how to use `specificSearch`.